# nestjs different beetween mongoose model provider and MongooseModule.forFeature

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

when I start to connect my nestjs app to MongoDB I see 2 different approaches for that
1- use MongooseModule.forFeature
2- use provider
in the first approach we have module like this

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: "COMPANY_MODEL", schema: CompanySchema}]),
        DatabaseModule
    ],
    controllers: [CompanyController],
    providers: [CompanyService,CityStateService],
})
```

and use InjectModel in service:

```
constructor(
        @InjectModel("COMPANY_MODEL")
        private companyModel: Model<ICompany>) { }
```

in a secend approach we have extra file `company.provider.ts` that contain:

```
export const CompanyProviders = [
    {
        provide: "COMPANY_MODEL",
        useFactory: (connection: Connection) => connection.model("Company", CompanySchema),
        inject: ["DATABASE_CONNECTION"],
    },
];
```

and we provide it in module like:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        DatabaseModule
    ],
    controllers: [CompanyController],
    providers: [CompanyService,CityStateService,...CompanyProviders],
})
export class CompanyModule { }
```

and in service we use simple Inject:

```
constructor(
            @Inject("COMPANY_MODEL")
            private companyModel: Model<ICompany>) { }
```

i wonder what is the different between these 2 approach in nestjs and which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference in these two approaches is that the first is what is official managed by the Nest package and the latter is what would be managed by you. The approaches are actually, in the end, identical, [as seen by the source code](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/master/lib/mongoose.providers.ts#L6), the only difference is that the first may be less repetitive over time without making a factory function for the provided model in the first place. Other than that, there's no differences, and you should go with what you are more comfortable with.